# How to optimize fetching data from database for PDF Convertion

Tags: laravel, dompdf

i have a problem to load the data from database , the system give me an error

```
Maximum Execution time off 60 seconds exceeded
```

i realize i need to optimze my code to shrink the time to load the data, I nearly have 10K of data in the table.

this is my code

```
public function export(Request $request){
    $fotoOutcomes= new FotoOutcomeCollection(FotoOutcome::with('user','outcomeCategory','paymentMethod')->select('name','cost','date','pcs')->get());  
    $pdf = PDF::loadView('FotoOutcomeExport/FotoOutcomeExport', compact('fotoOutcomes'));
    return $pdf->download('Foto-Outcome.pdf');

}
```

please help me to optimize this code, i have no idea about what should i do to optimize this code.
thankyou in advance

**UPDATE**
this is my view code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title>Document</title>

</head>
<body>
<div className="overflow-x-auto">
    <table className="table table-zebra w-full">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>No</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Pcs</th>
                <th>Cost</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @php $i=1 @endphp
            @foreach ($fotoOutcomes as $fotoOutcome)
            
            <tr>
                <th>{{$i}}</th>
                <td>{{$fotoOutcome->name}}</td>
                <td>{{$fotoOutcome->date}}</td>
                <td>{{$fotoOutcome->pcs}}</td>
                <td>{{$fotoOutcome->cost}}</td>
            </tr>
            @php $i++; @endphp
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have 10K of items, you are hydrating a *ton* of models in that query.  That takes time and memory.  Probably the most efficient way to reduce this would be to use a `DB` query and not fully hydrate the models.  Assuming your table is `foto_outcomes`:

```
$fotoOutcomes = \DB::table('foto_outcomes')->get();
```

However, this is still pulling in all of the information from that table.  You can further reduce the query time by not selecting `*`, and only applying the fields you need:

```
$fotoOutcomes = \DB::table('foto_outcomes')->select('name', 'date', 'pcs', 'cost')->get();
```

I see you have included three relationships in your original query.  If those are necessary, you will have to add them to the above query.  You can also add a select statement for those relations to save calling `*` on those relations.  However, if those items are on the original `foto_outcomes` table, you can skip them for a big jump in efficiency, using the query above.

Answer (score 2):

Please show the view from which you generate the pdf, I have the same issue when I try to use some Laravel helper function (In my case, I try to use the `asset()` function).

Try to use the `loop` variable instead of the `$i` variable

```
<tr>
 <th>{{$loop->index}}</th>
 <td>{{$fotoOutcome->name}}</td>
 <td>{{$fotoOutcome->date}}</td>
 <td>{{$fotoOutcome->pcs}}</td>
 <td>{{$fotoOutcome->cost}}</td>
</tr>
```

Or you can test with a smaller amount of data, if its fails the error is in the view

```
public function export(Request $request){
    $fotoOutcomes= new FotoOutcomeCollection(FotoOutcome::with('user','outcomeCategory','paymentMethod')->select('name','cost','date','pcs')->take(10)->get());  
    $pdf = PDF::loadView('FotoOutcomeExport/FotoOutcomeExport', compact('fotoOutcomes'));
    return $pdf->download('Foto-Outcome.pdf');

}
```

Comment: i already updated my question please check the view there

Answer (score 1):

You can use pagination to load data in small amount instead of loading all data at once.

```
public function export(Request $request){
    $pageSize = 100; // set the number of records to load per page
    $fotoOutcomes = FotoOutcome::with('user', 'outcomeCategory', 'paymentMethod')
        ->select('name', 'cost', 'date', 'pcs')
        ->paginate($pageSize); // use pagination to load data in smaller chunks
    $fotoOutcomes = new FotoOutcomeCollection($fotoOutcomes);
    $pdf = PDF::loadView('FotoOutcomeExport/FotoOutcomeExport', compact('fotoOutcomes'));
    return $pdf->download('Foto-Outcome.pdf');
}
```

you can change your for loop like this in view code.

```
@foreach ($fotoOutcomes as $fotoOutcome)
<tr>
    <th>{{ $fotoOutcomes->firstItem() + $loop->index }}</th>
    <td>{{ $fotoOutcome->name }}</td>
    <td>{{ $fotoOutcome->date }}</td>
    <td>{{ $fotoOutcome->pcs }}</td>
    <td>{{ $fotoOutcome->cost }}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: this mean the pdf will render 100 data in single A4 page?

Comment: It is an example only, you can set the range as you want to render data in single A4 page instead of loading all data,this will consume more running time , if load all data .